# Whats wrong with my buttons

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Whats wrong with my buttons? here http://hiddenbrookstudio.com/index.swf, see how they rollover and dissappear and takes a second for them to reappear they should look like this http://www.hiddenbrookstudio.com/popup.html . Not counting the last button what did I do wrong here? I am modifying code of a programmer who is not with my company anymore and I need to edit this for a friend, I can't tell what went wrong when I was editing the single button on the right hand side ( I know it has no animation yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at your timeline, it looks like they are lacking tweens and the frames inbetween the states are empty. It takes the same amount of time as the working version with fades, but all the fading frames are missing.